# javascript, jquery insert element when clicked inside text

Tags: javascript, jquery, insert

I'm trying to create a script that inserts an element when clicked inside an element that contains text.

Take a look at the picture below.

[image: example]

The A and B are mouse click positions of the end user.

So if the user would click on point A, the script has to insert an element between the lines where the click occured.

If the script would insert an element with a red background color, the result has to be like in the image below.

[image: result]

I honestly have no idea where to start, I found some WYSIWYG editors that use scripts to insert something at the carret position, but this is the cursor position and between 2 lines or at the end of a line. I really appreciate your help.

http://cdpn.io/nocfe

Comment: Can you provide at least some of your HTML for us to work with?

Comment: @mattytommo I added codepen doc to my question, will think about that in the future.

Comment: I may be wrong, but you'll almost certainly have to split your elements up into separate `p` tags for each line in order to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your markup is something like this:

```
<div class="text">
    <p>Thomas is rich...</p>
    <p>in the past...</p>
</div>
```

You could use [$.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) to insert the new element

```
$(".text p").click(function()
{
    $(this).after("<p>I'm the new element</p>");
});
```

Comment: Not every line is a new paragraph, this indead would solve the problem but this is not the case.

Comment: Another option would be to wrap each individual line in a span with a class, and replace the p selector with the class selector.